# How to boil a list down to least common strings?

Tags: c#

I have a `HashSet<string>` which I'm loading vulgar words into for filtering purposes.  The problem is that my list will contain "Fu" and also the word spelled out completely.  What I want to do is filter the list down so it only contains "Fu", which would eliminate any other forms of the word from the list.

In other words, I want to remove all strings in the list where its substring is also a list item.

How should I go about doing this?

I have the following where `excludedWords` is the original `HashSet`, but it's not working completely:

```
HashSet<string> copy = new HashSet<string>(exludedWords);

foreach (string w in copy)
{
    foreach (string s in copy)
    {
        if (w.Contains(s) && w.Length > s.Length)
        {
            result.Remove(w);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to filter out all words that *start* with "Fu", or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @djacobson -Start with or contain, although "Fu" is only an example.

Comment: [@djacobson](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_GHp3tbQtz24/SwuU19fj1MI/AAAAAAAAAUs/LtOyUWetyfI/s400/fuuuuuu.jpg), all words that start with another item in the set, it sounds like.

Comment: @bzlm I would say all "remove all words that contain any other word from the list"

Comment: That filtering plan is really *Fu*nny - Censored

Comment: So... remove foohead because foo is already in the list?

Comment: @BZink -Yes!  Exactly!  If randomly generated words with foo in them are eliminated, then words with foodhead in them are also eliminated without the extra loop itereations.

Comment: @OskarKjellin, that won't achieve what's intended though, right?

Comment: @bzlm -@OskarKjellin has it right.

Comment: @OskarKjellin, because they need to [*start*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640297/how-to-boil-a-list-down-to-least-common-strings/7640346#7640346) with the lowest common denominator. Otherwise words ending in "fu" would be removed as duplicates.

Comment: Think of least common denominator, but with strings instead of numbers.

Comment: @bzlm He wrote just a few comments above "Start with or contain"

Comment: @OskarKjellin, well, since starts-with is a subset of contains, I thought it was a typo. :)

Comment: You should use a [prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) as your data structure.  It will be much more efficient at searching for the strings.

Comment: @Jeff: I think this should be an answer.  From that data structure, the algorithm pretty much writes itself.

Comment: @JeffMercado -I'm welcome to the suggestion but I've never used a prefix tree before, can you flesh it out a bit more with an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should compare every word in the set to every other (distinctly different) word in the set.  You can accomplish this as follows (although I'm sure this is not the most efficient method, by any means):

```
string[] strings = { "a", "aa", "aaa", "b", "bb", "bbb", "c", "cc", "ccc" };
List<string> results = new List<string>(strings);

foreach (string str1 in strings) {
  foreach (string str2 in strings) {
    if (str1 != str2) {
      if (str2.Contains(str1)) {
        results.Remove(str2);
      }
    }
  }
}

return results;
```

Comment: -StartsWith() is not sufficient, but your example does suggest a method different than mine.  Instead of modifying the original list, copy it and work on the copy.  I'll try it.

Comment: @MAW74656, what's the rationale for using Contains rather than StartsWith? Why should "astrofunk" be removed because "fu" is in the list?

Comment: @bzlm -Because "fu" is the shortest common offensive substring of "astrofunk" and "fu*k".  I never said only remove starting with, a substring can start at any index within a string.

Comment: Sorry, based on your "fu" example, I interpreted this to mean `StartsWith`, but you can just as easily use `Contains`.

Comment: @JonathanNewmuis -Ok, your code works just like mine (but with less looping, so more efficient), which still has an issue.  The list has been boiled down, but not completely.  For example, I still have "AS", "ASS", and "AS5" in my list, where "AS" should be the only one.  Any thoughts on why?

Comment: @MAW74656, sounds like you'd get a lot of false positives in your filter.

Comment: @bzlm -I have to be extra careful to filter out offensive strings, so when I randomly generate strings, a lot do get thrown out.  That's why I want to boil down this list so the looping is reduced.

Comment: @MAW74656, sounds like your string generator could check each proposal against a contains-blacklist instead.

Comment: @MAW74656 - I've just run this code snippet above using `string[] strings = { "AS", "ASS", "AS5" };` as the input, and the result I get is just `AS`.  Not sure what's could be wrong there.  If you changed the condition, that could be why.

Comment: @JonathanNewmuis -I figured out the problem.  Of course I didn't have "AS" in the list.  Stupid me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way...

```
filter.RemoveAll(a => filter.Any(b => b != a && a.Contains(b)));
```

Where filter is a List and pre-populated with the filter strings.

Edit:
 Didn't see that you wanted Contains instead of starts with. so made the necessary mod.

Comment: -Ouch, lambda!  Would this perform better than looping?

Comment: No, but I didn't have my Assember editor available at the time to make the most performant solution. (I didn't see him mention any need for speed in his post)

Comment: -I just mean in general, which would perform better?  I understand its not perfect, although since I'm doing this once, then looping through the shortened list, performance on this action isn't as important.

Comment: This isn't the fastest as it is n^2 (all items compare against all other items and itself) whereas alternative solutions would never check against strings shorter then itself. I just like it's compactness and readability vs others and if you only have small database of words i'm sure it'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to throw away the longer values you could just use an `IEqualityComparer<string>` implementation to get the new set.

```
private class ShortestSubStringComparer : IComparer<string>, IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == null) return (y == null) ? 0 : -1;
        if (y == null) return 1;

        Debug.Assert(x != null && y != null);
        if (this.Equals(x, y)) return x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);
        return StringComparer.CurrentCulture.Compare(x, y);
    }

    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == null) return y == null;
        if (x.StartsWith(y)) return true;
        if (y != null && y.StartsWith(x)) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then your function can use the `GroupBy` function to group and select the first ordered item like so:

```
public HashSet<string> FindShortestSubString(HashSet<string> set)
{
    var comparer = new ShortestSubStringComparer();
    return new HashSet<string>(set.GroupBy(e => e, comparer).Select(g => g.OrderBy(e => e, comparer).First()));
}
```

Or possibly `Min` might do the trick (meaning you don't need the `IComparer<string>` implementation either)...

```
public HashSet<string> FindShortestSubString(HashSet<string> set)
{
    var comparer = new ShortestSubStringComparer();
    return new HashSet<string>(set.GroupBy(e => e, comparer).Select(g => g.Min(e => e)));
}
```

Comment: -My list can have several "least commons".  I need to get rid of the longer versions of words.  It sounds like this method is assuming only 1 least common stubstring per list?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against this type of filtering. You may save some cpu cycles but you'll get some unintended consequences that may really confuse your users (or just make them plain mad)

For example, let's assume that this is you list of vulgar words...

foo
bar
foohead
foolery

You want to filter out all of these words from some content. To be efficient you remove foohead and foolery and just filter on the substring foo.

You're going to filter innocuous words that contain foo but weren't in your orignal vulgar list.

reminds me of this recent Daily WTF... (second one down)

http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Progree-of-enail-Status.aspx

Comment: This is what I was getting at with my comment on the question. Unless I misunderstand what the OP is going to *do* with this reduced list of vulgar words, he's going to have this problem.

Comment: Yeah. I agree. It's a valid programming exercise and worth a real answer. But for this use case it's going to cause some real problems.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing the problem?  The only problem I see is that this filter will throw out some safe words (which is acceptable).  I don't care if my list contains "food" or not, so long as it doesn't contain "foohead".

Comment: The problem isn't in what ends up in your list. Your list would be correct. The problem comes when you try to use your list to do filtering against some user-submitted content (which we assume you're doing -- and we may be wrong)

Comment: @BZink, I think the idea is to make sure random generated strings don't possibly contain vulgarities. Not to filter web pages. :)

Comment: @BZink -I'm randomly generated strings, then checking them against this list.  If they have anything offensive, I throw the string out.  If they're safe, I save them in memory then later into a file.

Comment: @BZink -Although, if you could suggest a way to minimize these false positives, I'm sure that would help performance of my program also.

Comment: You could always just leave out vowels when you create the random strings. You can't have vulgar words if you don't have words to begin with. :)

Comment: @MAW74656 I think what we're getting at is to ensure the lowest-common-denominator words in your list will only match vulgarities. From your example, including "Fuc" in the filter list would result in far fewer false positives than would "Fu", because there are far fewer non-vulgar English words that begin with "Fuc". How to ensure this programmatically, I'm not sure: but therein is the potential problem. :)

Comment: @djacobson -I see what your saying, but in this case "Fu" has been deemed offensive.  So I have gone with the lowest common here, although I understand your point.

Comment: @BZink, fck ff, stnkng crp cdr!

Comment: @bzlm It's no surprise, given your username, that you hate vowels. :)